# Apache 2.4 webserver not starting when trying to load mod_jk.so

Tags: apache, startup, mod-jk

I have downloaded mod_jk.so and configured using apxs.

The apache instance is starting fine without

LoadModule    jk_module  /usr/lib64/apache/modules/mod_jk.so

But facing the error when I uncomment the above line in httpd.conf file

-- Unit httpd@httpdmyinstance01.service has begun starting up.

Apr 30 16:27:33 mylocal.host.com systemd[1]: httpd@httpdmyinstance01.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Apr 30 16:27:33 mylocal.host.com kill[115209]: kill: cannot find process ""

Apr 30 16:27:33 mylocal.host.com systemd[1]: httpd@httpdmyinstance01.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 30 16:27:33 mylocal.host.com systemd[1]: Failed to start httpd - httpdmyinstance01.

-- Subject: Unit httpd@httpdmyinstance01.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, there is a log file for mod_jk module.

and the system is not able to write to that particular log location.(its under root user)

Changed the log location and the issue is fixed.